# How to sort lines in select resquest to don't have multiple same lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I work with SQL Server 2008 and i try to do a stored procedure, which contains a select request.
I have a variable in parameter in the aim that the select resquest return the good datas. However, I get severals lines which are the same and I can't rid of these lines in my 
select request.
I use 3 Tables :
Table1, Table 2, Table 3 and i try to do this resquest :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bkd_GetContent]
    @MonIdPrecis int
AS
BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT DISTINCT tb3.Id,tb2.Nom,tb1.MonIdPrecis,tb3.Titre,tb1.Rang,tb3.Image
FROM  dbo.Table1 tb1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 tb2 ON tb2.Id = tb1.MonIdPrecis 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table3 tb3 ON tb3.Id = tb1.Id
WHERE tb1.MonIdPrecis = @MonIdPrecis  
     AND tb2.Activtb2ed = 1 
     AND tb3.Id IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY tb1.Rang

END
```

But I get multiples lines with the same tb3.Id with this resquest. 
The field Image might change to each ligne with the same Id. Most of the cas all the lines are the sames.( I don't put all the elements of each table in my select)
My aim is to get several tb3.id each different (that's why i try to use DISTINCT)
I also try to put `COUNT(*) AS ServeralLines` in my select and  `GROUP BY tb3.Id,tb2.Nom,tb1.MonIdPrecis,tb3.Titre,tb1.Rang,tb3.Image` but it don"t work on each lines.

It is possible or Does it exist a keyword like DISTINCT which is applied only on one field (tb3.Id) ? Can we use a tempory table in this case ?
I can't delete the boring lines which give me a problem.

Have you an idea to fix it ?

Comment: First, check if you are using the right join keys.

Comment: DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows, not just on the first column. What you have to decide is the expected result when one tb3.Id value have different values for the other columns, MAX/MIN/SUM/AVG etc? The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: I agree with you for the distinct, but it is possible to use a Same thing only on a field without look at the others ?

Comment: It is possible to go to what i want by using two request. First i do a select Distinct only on the "tb3.id", then for each id i select the top 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to make sure you are joining on the proper keys. Without knowing exactly how your data model looks like, it's difficult to answer the question.

There is no such thing as a "DISTINCT which is applied only on one field". This does not even make sense, since what would the output be on the columns for which you did not "apply" your DISTINCT?

However, what you could do, is use the `ROW_NUMBER` function, to assign a running value to each "block" of data from which you only want to return 1 record. In your case, I guess something like the following could work:

```
SELECT Id,Nom,MonIdPrecis,Titre,Rang,Image
FROM (
    SELECT tb3.Id,tb2.Nom,tb1.MonIdPrecis,tb3.Titre,tb1.Rang,tb3.Image,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tb3.Id ORDER BY tb1.Rang) AS RunningValue
    FROM  dbo.Table1 tb1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 tb2 ON tb2.Id = tb1.MonIdPrecis 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Table3 tb3 ON tb3.Id = tb1.Id
    WHERE tb1.MonIdPrecis = @MonIdPrecis  
        AND tb2.Activtb2ed = 1 
        AND tb3.Id IS NOT NULL 
) AS T
WHERE RunningValue = 1
ORDER BY tb1.Rang
```